# SQL Server : use generated ID column value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Small reproducible query:

```
INSERT INTO records (serial_number, cust_name) 
VALUES ('REGION_CODE' + IDENT_CURRENT('records'), 'CUST_NAME') 
OUTPUT Inserted.serial_number
```

The idea is to generate a serial number based on the autogenerated integer ID and `REGION_CODE` prefix stored separately which is different for each region which is looked up in the application code.

The problem is sometimes, there is a rare occurrence there are two queries which differ in seconds causing `IDENT_CURRENT('records')` to return the same ID. This causes two rows to have duplicated ID's. We have multiple transactions every second, but this duplicate ID incident only happens about once a month, so I am guessing there are some anomalies.

Is there a way to ensure that the `serial_number` generated will never be the same and relate to the current auto generated id?

We have tried using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, but it seems to return lagged id.

Triggers won't work since we need to return the inserted serial_number

Comment: I very much doubt one can reproduce anything with your query since 'region_code' cannot be cast to INT. The normal way is to do: output inserted.identitycolumn to get the newly inserted value, your way is backward

Comment: Why don't youy do that in a view ? CREATE VIEW V_records
AS
SELECT CONCAT('REGION_CODE', ID) AS serial_number,
       *
FROM   records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just make this a **computed** column inside SQL Server?

Then you don't need to insert values into it at all - it will automagically show the appropriate "constructed" ID for you.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Records
    ADD Serial_Number AS CONCAT(Region_Code, RecordsId);
```

I *guessed* that your primary key column is called `RecordsId` - if it's something else, adapt as needed.

This will concatenate together the contents of your `Region_Code` and your `RecordsId` column and surface that as a new column `Serial_Number` in your `Records` table.

Any time you insert a value like this:

```
INSERT INTO records (cust_name) 
VALUES ('CUST_NAME');
```

the primary key (auto-generated by the `IDENTITY` spec) will be incremented, and the `Serial_Number` column will be automagically set to the expected value. No more need to fiddle with getting the `ID` value from the `INSERT` and inserting the value for `Serial_Number` yourself - let SQL Server take care of that for you